# Getting NaN error while typeof() shows number

Tags: javascript

so I'm writing this very simple function and I'm trying to return it's result but all I get is `NaN` error.

Here is my current code:

```js
function m(c) {
    return Math.max(c) - this.length - 1;
}


document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = m([1,4,6,8,43,2]);
```

```html
<p id="app">

</p>
```

When I `return typeof(a - this.length -1);` instead, I get a `number` as a result.

```js
    function m(c) {
        return typeof(Math.max(c) - this.length - 1);
    }


    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = m([1,4,6,8,43,2]);
```

```html
<p id="app">

</p>
```

So my question is why am I getting `NaN` error if type of my return statement is a number?

@edit Question number 2. Is there a way for me to change the function so that it displays the result without NaN error?

Comment: what is `Math.max(c)` supposed to do?

Comment: what is `this`? please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) is of the `number` type:

```js
console.log(typeof NaN)
```

The reason you're getting `NaN` is that you can't just call `Math.max` on an array. (Try `Math.max([1,2])`). You'll need to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`).

Also, I assume you meant to use the array's length, since `this.length` doesn't refer to anything.:

```js
function m(c) {
    return Math.max(...c) - c.length - 1;
}


console.log(m([1,4,6,8,43,2]));
```

In case you need to [support older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility), replace `Math.max(...c)` with:

```
Math.max.apply(null, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Math.max.apply(null, c)`.
Math.max takes a list of numbers, not an array. That's why you have to use apply to use the array as a argument list.

Comment: Mdn docs: However, both spread (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements, because they try to pass the array elements as function parameters. See Using apply and built-in functions for more details. The reduce solution does not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` context is not bound with that array, you can bind it as follow, further, you need to sort the array and get the max value.

```js
function m() {
  var [max] = this.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return max - this.length - 1;
}

document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = m.bind([1, 4, 6, 8, 43, 2])();
```

```html
<p id="app"></p>
```

**Or you can Spread the array:**

```js
function m(c) {
  return Math.max(...c) - c.length - 1;
}

document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = m([1, 4, 6, 8, 43, 2]);
```

```html
<p id="app"></p>
```

Comment: `sort` to get the largest value? `.bind` to work around abuse of `this`? I'd suggest changing the OP's methodology instead of making their hacks "work".

Answer (score 1):

this.length is undefined. Replace it with c.length.

Also, math.max doesn't work as you think.
If you look at the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Getting_the_maximum_element_of_an_array) you can see that they recommend a reduce function for arrays.

> However, both spread (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array has too many elements, because they try to pass the array elements as function parameters. See Using apply and built-in functions for more details. The reduce solution does not have this problem.

So in short.

```js
function m(c) {
   
    var max = c.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Math.max(a, b);
    });
    return max - c.length - 1;
}


document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = m([1,4,6,8,43,2]);
```

```html
<p id="app">

</p>
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? The reduce function literally comes from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Getting_the_maximum_element_of_an_array